# Get aggregate of aggregate by group PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, aggregate, dax

I have a data set that is aggregated by supplier month/name/location/division and shows the mean and the count of each group as follows:

| Month | name | location | division | mean | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dec | Globalf | GC | Sales | 4 | 2 |
| Dec | localF | GC | Sales | 5.44 | 27 |
| Dec | Globalf | GC | Purchasing | 0.00 | 2 |
| Dec | Globalf | NC | Sales | 3 | 1 |

I would like to create a dax formula that gives me the average of the current group ie:

| Month | location | division | mean | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dec | GC | Sales | 5.341 | 29 |
| Dec | GC | Purchasing | 0.00 | 2 |
| Dec | NC | Sales | 3 | 1 |

Average of averages isn't what I am looking for as AVERAGEX gives me an incorrect result.
I have also tried multiplying but this does it on the grouped value so is giving a wrong result:

```
grp_average = SUM('tbl'[mean]) * SUM('tbl'[count])
```

Is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a weighted average

```
grp_average = DIVIDE ( SUMX( 'tbl', 'tbl'[mean] * 'tbl[count] ), SUM( 'tbl'[count] ) )
```